# Accessing AngularJS Directive Scope in Link function

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm writing a directive. Currently, my directive looks like the following:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(component) {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.tpl.html',
    scope: {
      myAttribute: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.myAttribute);
    }
  };
})
```

I want to use this directive in my HTML like the following:

```
<myDirective myAttribute="true"></myDirective>
```

My question is, how do I get the value of 'myAttribute' in the link function of my directive? I need to get that value to do some programmatic stuff. However, my current approach always prints 'undefined' to the JavaScript console.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your HTML you need to convert the camel case names in your directive definition to pascal case, so your HTML should be:

```
<my-directive my-attribute="true"></my-directive>
```

and as for how to access them in the link function, simple:

```
var value =scope.myAttribute;
```

Comment: Doh! That translation gets me everytime. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Carefull of the camel case syntax. You must populate your attribute like that :

```
<myDirective my-attribute="true"></myDirective>
```

Tricky ...